# Error "File or directory corrupted" when an MVC template is being loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

#### How do we deploy the application

1. Publish to local filesystem with Visual Studio.
2. Create an application on production server (IIS)
3. Copy the files to the app directory

#### There is an error in our production server.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The disk structure is corrupted and unreadable.


Source Error: 

Line 1:  <div class="row-fluid">Line 2:    <div id="graph" class="span24">Line 3:    </div>

Source File: /Views/ProductionOrder/ProductionOrderFlow.cshtml    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

I have checked the file system and no error found.

The template file can be successfully opened with notepad.

Any other possible reasons?

Comment: How did you copied those files to server?

Comment: Hi Floradu88. I publish the project with publish-Local filesystem. And then copy the files to remote server.

Comment: Have you tried to recover bad sectors using: `chkdsk /r`?

Comment: Did you use a shared folder to do that?

Comment: No, I made a copy of these files.

Comment: Why don't you use deploy feature?

Comment: The server is in a private network and we can not access directly. We deliver these files to our client. They do the deployment.

Comment: @leoleozhu check my answer for a possible reason of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a shared folder in order to copy the files, you may check this answer from super user: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a). Your files might be blocked due to security reasons. Right click and properties for the root folder to check for this.

Second option might be replacing the hard disk drive of the server.

Third option might be different file encoding between your computer and live computer.

Comment: If the file is blocked due to security reasons. I do not think the leading lines could be read by our application. How do you think?

Comment: You provided scarce information for this issue. This is what I encountered so far with the information in the question.